# Eigenvectors of Kneser graphs

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

The **eigenvalues** of the adjacency matrix of a **Kneser graph** are known (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph). Are the **eigenvectors** known?

Comment: The obvious thing to do would be to track down the citation on Wikipedia and see if it also gives the eigenvectors.